# How to show a dom from angular factory

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom

I want to show a dom with a spinner image from factory, i tried using the jquery, $rootScope to show the dom with no success,

Below is my factory code,

```
.factory('api', function($q, $http, $state, $timeout, $rootScope, $window) {
    var request = function(callback, timeout) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      $timeout(function() {
        deferred.resolve(null);
      }, typeof timeout !== 'undefined' ? timeout : 800);

      callback(deferred);

      return deferred.promise;
    };

    return {
      postData: postData
    };

    function postData(data) {
      var $ = angular.element;
      $.sg= true;
      return $http.post('/a/', data).then(function(response) {
          $timeout(function () {window.location.href = "/bdc";}, 10000)
        }
      })
    }
  })
```

Comment: I'm still waiting for a response in your question before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44085782/show-image-background-on-md-select-md-options-on-hover-in-angularjs-1-6  .. Could you please provide some feedback on my answer there? I fixed your problem in that question and it took me more than 1 hour. It would be glad if you could bring some feedback so

Answer (score 0):

I think your intention is to show a `spinner` for all the Http requests in your application. The one I used was `angular-block-ui` module.

http://angular-block-ui.nullest.com/#!/examples/documentation

Also its not a good idea to access some DOM elements from a factory. Factory is meant for doing some re-usable code which can be injected to your controllers, directives etc.

**autoBlock**

> By default the BlockUI module will start a block whenever the Angular
>   $http service has an pending request. If you don't want this behaviour
>   and want to do all the blocking manually you can change this value to
>   false.

```
// Disable automatically blocking of the user interface
blockUIConfig.autoBlock = false;
```

Make use of `requestFilter` option in `block-ui` to filter your requests, if you don't want to show it for all request.

If you choose for Manual blocking, use the `start()` and `stop()` method to show and hide the blocking.

```
<div block-ui="myBlockUI">
  <p> ... I'm blockable ... </p>
</div>
```

> The `block-ui` directive takes an optional value, which can be used to
>   get an instance of the associated blockUI service.

```
// Get the reference to the block service.
var myBlockUI = blockUI.instances.get('myBlockUI');

// Start blocking the element.
myBlockUI.start();

$timeout(function() {
  // Stop the block after some async operation.
  myBlockUI.stop();
}, 1000);
```

The above blocking is expected to be done from Controllers not from Factory.

Manual blocking example: http://plnkr.co/edit/qflWqd?p=preview

Auto blocking example: http://embed.plnkr.co/NqyunD/

Comment: In that case, I can use the spinner in the resolve of bdc url to check if the response is completed, correct me if I'm wrong